# How to use ternary operator in json mapping to java objects (using xml data)

Tags: java, json, mapping, ternary-operator

I am trying to figure out how to map xml data to Java objects, Say I have the line of json

```
"blankDate": "?SecurityDate == =BLANK? =true : =false"
```

I am trying to map blankDate to a  Java boolean, and SecurityDate to a LocalDate

For some reason, during the mapping, the blankDate is never set, so it is null. However I need it to be true or false. I used this example code

```
"securityDate": "?SecurityDate != BLANK? SecurityDate : =null"
```

To try to form my earlier statement. This statement does work(Or I think it is).

I have tried search for JSON ternary conditionals but can't any thing on this. Could some lead me in the right direction(Source to learn from)? Thanks.

Comment: blankDate is not a boolean. It's a string. And its value is the string `"?SecurityDate == =BLANK? =true : =false"`. JSON is a data format. It's not a programming language. It doesn't have expressions, conditionals, or whatever. All it has is data, which can be null, strings, numbers, booleans, arrays and objects. So I have absolutely no idea of what you're asking.

Comment: @JBNizet I updated my question. I mean't to say I am mapping to Java objects. Thanks for your superfluous explanation of JSON. The question still is, how cant I include conditionals in a JSON string in the mapping process.

Comment: You'll have to show us your actual Java code, and explain what you want to achieve. All you posted is a single line that looks like it is the property of a JSON object, but contains something that looks like an expression, in an unknown language, hence the superfluous explanation. The fact that you consider the explanation superfluous, but that you're nevertheless looking for "JSON ternary conditionals" (I quote), is troubling too.